# 2 select forms using on.(change) jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**this is the php file for my project. It displays correctly but the problem is the jquery doesn't do his work. if i select in deps i assume that only in the same value will be displayed in courses. but sadly it doesn't work. please help.**

```
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
    <select name="deps" id="deps">
        <option selected="selected" value=""> - department -</option>
        <option value="md">Masteral Degree</option>
        <option value="cd">College Degree</option>
        <option value="hs">High School</option>
        <option value="gs">Grade School</option>
    </select>

    <select name="courses" id="courses">
        <option selected="selected" value=""> - course/year/grade -</option>
        <option value="md">Master of Arts (MA)</option>
        <option value="md">Master of Science (MSc)</option>
        <option value="cd">Bachelor of Science in Accountancy (BSA)</option>
        <option value="cd">Bachelor of Science in Civil Engineering (BSCE)</option>
        <option value="hs">2nd year</option>
        <option value="hs">1st year</option>
        <option value="gs">Grade 2</option>
        <option value="gs">Grade 1</option>
    </select>
```

**and this is the jquery that doesn't do anything**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#deps").on("change", function() {
var $dep = $(this).val(), 
    $course = $("#courses");
if (!$dep) { 
  $course.find("option").show(); $course.val(''); 
} 
else {
  $course.find("option").hide(); 
  $course.find("option[value*='" + $dep + "']").show().prop('selected', true);
}
});
});
```

**what was the problem with this? any solution?**

Comment: Your code has no problem. I have tested in [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/fLasry6L/)

Comment: Same here. Could you activate your console and watch the logs ? There must be an error elsewhere in your JS file.

Comment: I tested your code amd found no issues

https://jsfiddle.net/cvecy2cv/

Comment: Please see your console to figure out an error. There may be an error, or it may be possible that you are missing JQuery file on the top of your page before another JQuery script

Answer (score 0):

It is working. I believe you haven't used `jQuery`. So add jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#deps").on("change", function() {
    var $dep = $(this).val(),
      $course = $("#courses");
    if (!$dep) {
      $course.find("option").show();
      $course.val('');
    } else {
      $course.find("option").hide();
      $course.find("option[value*='" + $dep + "']").show().prop('selected', true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="deps" id="deps">
        <option selected="selected" value=""> - department -</option>
        <option value="md">Masteral Degree</option>
        <option value="cd">College Degree</option>
        <option value="hs">High School</option>
        <option value="gs">Grade School</option>
    </select>

<select name="courses" id="courses">
        <option selected="selected" value=""> - course/year/grade -</option>
        <option value="md">Master of Arts (MA)</option>
        <option value="md">Master of Science (MSc)</option>
        <option value="cd">Bachelor of Science in Accountancy (BSA)</option>
        <option value="cd">Bachelor of Science in Civil Engineering (BSCE)</option>
        <option value="hs">2nd year</option>
        <option value="hs">1st year</option>
        <option value="gs">Grade 2</option>
        <option value="gs">Grade 1</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: All I have done is included jQuery. You need to include jQuery in your script tag at the top. You can either use CDN or locally downloaded version

Comment: Thanks for the answers but it doesn't work with me. What should i do?

Comment: i use sublime text for both files. is that the problem?

Comment: Could you add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` before body tag and check

Answer (score 0):

I have write javascript code..please used this script.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#deps').on("change", function() {
            if($(this).val()){
                deps= $(this).val();
                $("#courses option").each(function(){
                    course=$(this).val();
                    if(course==deps){ // EDITED THIS LINE
                            $('#courses option[value="' + deps + '"]').prop('selected', true);
                        }
                });
            }
        })  
    });

</script>
```